# Move actual file instead of a link to other project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2015, file-moving

I've been a working with java and Eclipse up until now and moving files between directories was quite easy, just drag & drop and you're done.

Now I moved to Visual Studio 2015 due to C++. So I accidentally created a file in the wrong project and wanted to move it to the right one. However, VS just creates a link to the real file which is still in the other project instead of actually moving the file. To solve this, I used my system explorer but is there a way to do this in Visual Studio directly?

This is extremely annoying. 2 files were missing after I exported my project a few days ago.

Comment: There is no "law" that requires source files to live in their hosting project's folder. In fact, different files belonging to one project may be located in different folders. Where exactly would you like your file to be moved?

Comment: I'd like to move the file from solution A to solution B.

Comment: A "solution" is just a set of properties and a list of contained projects.

Comment: Ah sorry, I have to correct myself. I mean project, not solution^^ I'm working with the german version hence the translation mistake.

Comment: Hmmm... OK: A "project" is just a set of properties and a list of contained files. My point is: you CAN'T move a file into a project's folder; there simply is no such folder.

Comment: Seems to be the case. However, I found a solution: tick "show all files" and then just drag&drop the file from one project to the other, works perfectly fine. Instead just making a link, it now moves the file physically!